# AudioBufferList passed to ABReceiverPortReceive does not match clientFormat when using The Amazing Audio Engine

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio

Hi I need multiple input streams form audiobus and I am using TAAE framework...

I tired this just to test if I can manually send audio :

`AEBlockChannel *channel = [AEBlockChannel channelWithBlock:^(const AudioTimeStamp *time, UInt32 frames, AudioBufferList *audio) { 
    ABReceiverPortReceive(_abreceiverPort, nil, audio, frames, time);
}];`

and I get "AudioBufferList passed to ABReceiverPortReceive does not match clientFormat "

What should I do ? I try to understand how TAAE works from its source but was not able to understand how I can create correct AudioBufferList, maybe some little example will enlighten me.

I found just this in sources AEAllocateAndInitAudioBufferList(rawAudioDescription, kInputAudioBufferFrames) , how it is created..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recieved answer from **Michael Tyson** on audiobus forum.

Please read http://developer.audiob.us/doc/_receiver-_port.html#Receiving-Separate-Streams

Specifically, see the part about ABReceiverPortEndReceiveTimeInterval.